# Django: How to hide all language prefix from urls while using i18n patterns

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Currently, I am using i18n patterns. It can hide the default language prefix but do not hide another language prefix. Is there any other way to hide all the prefixes of languages and our local middleware will get the current language from currently set cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this issue by removing i18n_patterns from urlpatterns as shown below.

This is my final output.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('', include('portal.urls', namespace='portal')),
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),
    path(_('accounts/'), include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('fluent_pages.urls')),
]
```